# Making own Alert dialogs extending AppCompatDialogFragment

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make my own Alert dialogs using "utility" class that extends AppCompatDialogFragment. But when I try to set my own messages, they didn't change, but the default ones of the class I created continue to appear.
For example in my AlertDialogConnection class I made Override of onCreateDialog, but in my activity, while I perform http request, I can't make my own texts.

*My own class that extends AppCompatDialogFragment*

```
public class AlertDialogConnection extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    private Builder builder;
    private String title;
    private String text;

    public AlertDialogConnection(){
        this.builder = null;
        this.text = "";
        this.title = "";
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if((this.title == "") || (this.text == "") || (this.builder == null)){
            this.builder = new Builder(getActivity());
            this.builder.setTitle("Error");
            this.builder.setMessage("Default Error: Error! try later");
            this.builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
        }else {
            this.builder = new Builder(getActivity());
            this.builder.setTitle(this.title);
            this.builder.setMessage(this.text);
            this.builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
        }
        return builder.create();
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

*Some code using that class*
in this class, in case of error I continue to see the default error of the class AlertDialogConnection, instead of my serverError title and text.

```
private AlertDialogConnection serverError = new AlertdialogConnection();

    private void requestData(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
            final Intent intent = new Intent(this, ModelResultData.class);
            httpClient.connectTimeoutMillis(); //server timeout
            httpClient.writeTimeoutMillis();
            httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    Log.d("HTTP-Error", "HTTP request error!");
                    AlertDialogConnection errorDialog = new AlertDialogConnection();
                    errorDialog.setTitle("server error!");
                    errorDialog.setText("server messaging error, try later");
                    errorDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "messaging error!");
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "results not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        /* HTTP-code: 200 */
                        final String body = response.body().string();
                        ModelSearchActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                intent.putExtra("ACTIVITY_SOURCE", "ModelSearchActivity");
                                intent.putExtra("json_data", body);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        //System.out.println(response.code());
                        //if (response.code() == 403) {
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "results not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //} else if (response.code() == 500) {
                            /* Http-code: 500 */
                            Log.d("HTTP-Error", "server error!");
                            serverError.setTitle("server error!");
                            serverError.setText("server error, try later");
                            serverError.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "server error!");
                        //}
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I have tried making comparisons with response code, but nothing change.

Answer (score 1):

The default value (in the constructor) you've set for `builder` is null.
This causes it to always get through the `if` condition since `builder == null` would return true. Try something along the following lines,

```java
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.builder = new Builder(getActivity());
        if(this.title.isEmpty() || this.text.isEmpty()){
            this.builder.setTitle("Error");
            this.builder.setMessage("Default Error: Error! try later");
            this.builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
        }else {
            this.builder.setTitle(this.title);
            this.builder.setMessage(this.text);
            this.builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
        }
        return builder.create();
    }
```

Comment: Or alternatively add a method for setBuilder() just like he did for setTitle and setText

Comment: @GiddyNaya Sure, that would work, but is there any reason he would want to do that? Create a separate function for something that should be created by default?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a separate utility for creating your own alert dialogue you can simply create a view and use the setView method to show that view in your app. See the snippet below

```
private void showDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sortdialog,null);//Replace it
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
    alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

This will allow you to create custom alert dialog boxes using the layout which you have created